# GWTTestcase accessing javascript object defined in an external javascript file fails

Tags: gwt, junit

I have defined a GWT module that includes an external javascript file using  tag. I have written a GWTTestCase that returns the above described module's name. When my testcase accesses a javascript object I see the following exception

Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null): null

Any idea on how to fix this?

Am I right in assuming that the scripts included in the gwt module definition file will be available when executing the GWTTestCase?

Comment: When I invoke the page after running the module in hosted mode, using firebug I can see that all the external javascript files are included properly and the javascript object defined in them are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it myself. Apparently, when accessing such objects it should be referenced using $wnd variable.

Example: test.js defined object test. In order to access it from GWT one should use, $wnd.test

Hope this answers saves somebody else' time.